# helm list --filter regex (not followed by)

Tags: regex, filter, kubernetes-helm, operator-keyword

How does one do a "not followed by" regex with helm list --filter?

Example deployment names:

- fruit-candy-bar
- fruit-candy-cane
- fruit-candy-ball
- fruit-icecream

I tried this, but it matches characters and also leaves out icecream:

```
helm list --filter 'fruit-[^candy]+'
```

Then I tried this to match "candy", but this also leaves out icecream:

```
helm list --filter 'fruit-[(?!candy)]+'
```

**UPDATE:**

I ended up using JQ and post process the json result to the desired output:

```
helm list -o json --all-namespaces | jq -r '.[] | select((.name | contains("fruit-")) and ((.name | contains("fruit-candy") | not))) | {name: .name}' | jq -s '.'
```

Comment: Not sure what you are after, but maybe you can try: [`^fruit(?:-(?!candy\b)[a-z]+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/zdnmSe/3)

Comment: Then I get this error:

"Error: error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`"

Not sure if this a limitation of helm.

Comment: I am not familiar with helm unfortunately. But if you have documentation, I'm sure we can figure it out. Does helm require you to do a double escape at `\\b` possibly?

Comment: The [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_list/) only mention the regex it supports is Perl-compatible, but a lot of references mention something similar without reason. If lookarounds are not supported, all you can do it use negated character classes (bracket expressions) to emulate the lookarounds, but the patterns like that look ugle and quickly become unweildly.

Comment: Thnx guys for taking the time to investigate this issue. I ended up using JQ and process the json result afterwards.